# Split and join string in c#

Tags: c#, string, join, split

I need to split the string to individual string and seperate by comma

var str = "2,1"

desired output:

str = "2", "1"

I tried below, but not working.

```
query.Add(new Parameters()
                                {
                                    labels = new List<string> { "test" },
                                    values = new List<string> { str.Split(',') }
                            });
```

I need to send like,
`values = "2", "3" }`

How to achieve this in c# ?

Comment: Well you answered your own question

Comment: You cannot say var str = "2", "1". Do you need it to be written in file. or you mean var str = "\"2\",\"1\""?

Comment: You need to provide more details of your code. We don't know what are Parameters, query, labels and values.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrSplittedStr = str.Split(",");
```

I you want string as a output like `str = "2", "1"` then try `str.Replace(",","\",\"")`

Comment: As per SO policies we are not providing code writing services, which means we won't answer questions that describe a scenario and ask help for code. If you answers such questions means it will degrade the quality of the site and its policies

Comment: @un-lucky - Can you please provide a reference to the policy and any discussions on Meta?

Comment: @un-lucky - Sorry to violating policies that you are referring. But if there is a question, it has to be an answer. The policies that you'r pointing must have to follow before asking such a question

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Split` Function in `C#`

```
 var str = "2,1"
 string[] ans = str.Split(',');
```

`Split` function return a string array.
now in ans array

```
 ans[0] = "2"
 ans[1] = "1"
```

Comment: As per SO policies we are not providing code writing services, which means we won't answer questions that describe a scenario and ask help for code. If you answers such questions means it will degrade the quality of the site and its policies

Comment: @un-lucky - Can you please provide a reference to the policy and any discussions on Meta?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I don't have any thread as proof, at the starting of my SO career one of the moderator advised me that don't promote low quality posts by answering them that may violate site policies. So I'm following them

Comment: @un-lucky - This seems to be the closest meta discussion on this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x/253096#253096 - so I'd suggest just going with the downvote/ignore approach.